# One fake monitor appears, which is connected to Intel(R) UHD Graphics, when in Nvidia Control Panel, I set Display mode: Nvidia GPU only

Tags: windows, laptop, freeze, gpu, intel-graphics

This happens from time to time when starting the laptop. My model is Lenovo Legion 5 15ITH6H.
Here are my specs:

- Processor 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-11400H
- GPU(processor): Intel(R) UHD Graphics
- GPU(nvidia): NVIDIA RTX 3060 Mobile

The appearance of a fake monitor, which is connected to Intel UDH Graphics, spits out micro friezes every 1 second, which clearly interferes with work.

I found a temporary solution to this problem, but I want to fix it once and for all.

Here is my solution:

I go to the Control Panel, and disable Intel(R) UHD Graphics in the Display adapters list. After that, the fake monitor disappears and the micro-friezes stop, but it all comes back after the laptop is restarted.

Comment: i already tried reinstralling drivers and it didn't helped

Comment: Not a "fake monitor"...